# SQL "excluding" Alphanumeric condition not working

Tags: sql, sybase

I know there are many forum discussions, but I think my situation is unique,  I am trying to look for all the address1 fields which does not have alpha numeric values, I just queried with the basic sql ( Database is Sybase ) , like below

```
select  address1 from address_table where address1 like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

My resultset is including alpha numeric values,

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~
1304 LOVERS LN
1304 LOWE AVE
1304 LYNCHBURG ST #1
1304 LYNCHBURG ST #1
1304 LYNNWOOD DR
~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am not sure what am I missing

Comment: Your understanding of how the pattern is being applied is flawed; your matches are likely coming from both whitespace and `#` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your ask correctly, you'll need more specificity in your pattern to match records whose `address1` contain **no** alphanumeric characters anywhere in the string.

Leverage the greedy repeating modifier `*` to check each character in the string against the pattern.

```
select address1 from address_table where address1 like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]*%'
```

Comment: yes, thank you it worked exactly what I was looking for.. thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You're matching anything that has at least one non-alphanumeric character.
You want instead a negative:

```
select  address1 from address_table where address1 not like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```